# Kivy spinner on_text_changed event

Tags: kivy, spinner

I'd like to react to the event when the `spinner` changes value and capture that value.
Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        mainbox = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal",
                            spacing=15,
                            padding=5)
        self.spinner_languages = Spinner(text ="", 
                values =("Python", "Java", "C++", "C", "C#", "PHP"), 
                size_hint = (0.3, 0.2)
                # on_text_changed = self.spinner_text_changed
                )
        mainbox.add_widget(self.spinner_languages)

        return mainbox

    #def spinner_text_changed(self, text):
    #    self.language = text
    #    print(self.language)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

The commented lines are what I'd like to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `bind` to trigger the `spinner_text_changed()` method when the `text` property changes, like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        mainbox = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal",
                            spacing=15,
                            padding=5)
        self.spinner_languages = Spinner(text ="",
                values =("Python", "Java", "C++", "C", "C#", "PHP"),
                size_hint = (0.3, 0.2)
                )
        self.spinner_languages.bind(text=self.spinner_text_changed)
        mainbox.add_widget(self.spinner_languages)

        return mainbox

    def spinner_text_changed(self, spinner, text):
       self.language = text
       print(self.language)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I believe it works, but is there some trick how to achieve selection of a language (e.g. Python) with the mouse on Desktop? I believe that it works when tapping on mobile phone, but on computer screen I can't achieve another selection than the default.

Comment: Just click on the `Spinner`, and the choices should display.

Comment: When I click with the mouse on the spinner choices will display, but I'm unable to select any choice. It will collapses very quickly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior.